# Oracle Apex List of values selection and button disable upon repetition of same selection

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I have an interactive report with two regions.

The first region is static region with a select list and  a button to submit the process.

The second region is the report region which refreshes the region based on first region select list  value and Process (calculate) button submitted.

However if  I try to submit same item (List of values) subsequently the process button must be disabled. (i.e) Any repetition of same List of values, once calculation or process is performed, the calculate button must be disabled and these are all based on input selection from front end.

Please note  there is not any direct relationship between the Select list button (Page item)  and second region columns and I cannot achieve it by distinguishing at database level if it is processed or unprocessed, as there is not any column maintained in database tables (in this case second region about year which is processed).

How can process be disabled second time?

and only if select list for quarter is entered for first time the process button (Calculate) must be enabled based on.

The second region values are populated/refreshed by swapping the columns  `this_year_q1` to `last_year_q1`, `last_year_q1` to `year_before_last_year_q1` etc., if calculate button is enabled and process is called.

[image]

So in below case, the calculate  button is  enabled  when select list  is (`Quarter is Q4:01/10/2017 to 31/12/2017`),  this is fine and must allow process  for first time.

Subsequent reselection of same value  must not allow process to calculate.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSb4D.png):

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

- create a (hidden) page text item
- using a dynamic action on a button

  - compare current Select List item's value with hidden item's value (don't forget the NVL function!)
  - if they don't match, put current (selected) Select List item value into the hidden item so that you could check it when the button is pressed once again (i.e. whether user selected the same value or not) and submit
  - if they match, do nothing (don't submit)

If you don't want to run the report twice not only for subsequent executions but during the session, you'd have to store selected values somewhere (a table?). The rest would be the same - you'd only have to select from that table and compare Select List's values with values already used.

Comment: Thanks for hidden item tip.  I am looking for button to be disabled during the session  for second time  if it  hasbeen used once in list of value as well as when I run it later also when I go out of session and  run it later also Can't this be done without storing in table like  a global variable or application item like an array